# Get session data in custom library - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am trying to get session data in a custom library within Codeigniter. But I can't seem to get any of the session data.

Following the user guide on Codeigniters website, I used the "magic getter" method to retrieve session data, as seen below --

```
public function __construct(){
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->library('session');
        $this->CI->db->select('id, first_name, last_name, email, password, logkey');
        $this->CI->db->from('jive_users');
        $this->CI->db->where('id', $this->CI->session->id);
        $this->CI->db->where('logkey', $this->CI->session->logkey);
        $result = $this->CI->db->get();
        if($result->num_rows() == 1){
            $row = $result->row();
            $this->id = $row->id;
            $this->first_name = $row->first_name;
            $this->last_name = $row->last_name;
            $this->email = $row->email;
            $this->password = $row->password;
            $this->logkey = $row->logkey;
        }

    }
```

I've also tried:

```
$this->CI->session->userdata('id')
$_SESSION['id']
```

I just cannot seem to get any session data whatsoever.

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Where do you set_userdata?

Comment: I set the session data in a model after a user logs in. I'm able to print the session data in my view. But unable to access it inside my library.

Comment: Shouldnt $result be `$result  = $this->CI->db->get('table')->result();`

Comment: This works fine if I manually input the users ID and Logkey. But once replaced with the session, I get nothing.

Comment: Looks fine to me, try using `var_dump($this->CI->session->id);exit;` after you load the library to see what value it is.

Comment: Hmm interesting, reloaded the page and just get NULL. I checked the logs and this is what I found: 

**ERROR - 2016-06-20 09:32:30 --> Severity: Error --> Call to undefined method CI_Session::id() /home/tesla/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/application/libraries/Acct.php 20**

Comment: Try loading the session library before you load this library.  I would do this first, but if that doesnt work.  Try creating a helper method to hande your session data.

Comment: Well that's the thing, I've actually just Autoloaded the library and the issue still persists. However, I AM able to get the session data like this: `$_SESSION['logged_in']['id']`. Which kind of sucks cause I liked the idea of using the methods CI uses to retrieve data. I guess we'll have to keep tweaking until we get it right.

Comment: I believe its the sequence in which the codeigniter files are executed.  I have a similar library and use a helper function to do this and it works.  Good luck.

Comment: So what did you do in your helper? Just load the session library or?

Comment: @JasonBassett : it is not a good practice to access or set session in model. Best practice is to do it in controller.
- So you can create a codeigniter library and call the library function in every controller , It is easy to code and also in modifying the code